# Name of Mysql database folder

Tags: mysql

I try to access to mysql data via filezilla and download to my pc,
What is name of folder where is my mysql data ?
I use ubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, most packages in most distributions in Linux, including official and distributions ones on Ubuntu set the default MySQL datadir on **`/var/lib/mysql`**. You can check the actual datadir by connecting to mysql and executing:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like 'datadir';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| datadir       | /var/lib/mysql/ |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Technically, there could be files outside of the datadir (per-table configuration, innodb files, etc.), but not with the default configuration.

Please note that, in general, that directory is owned by the `mysql` user, so you will not be able to read or write it as a regular user. Only the `mysql` system user or a user with administration privileges will be able to access there.

If you are using Filezilla, you probably will be using ftp/sftp/ssh. Please note that copying the files directly has the following restrictions:

- You can only do it consistently if the server has been stopped. **Otherwise you will end up with a corrupt set of files.**
- The files you will copy can only be used as a backup, or to clone the current setup, you cannot access the tables unless you set up a new mysql instance on your local pc
- You may want to copy other files like logs (`/var/log/mysql*`) and the configuration files (`/etc/my*`)

If you want simply to access the mysql service/data remotely and operate with it, you do not need filezilla, only a mysql client, like the [mysql monitor command line](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html), [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) or [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/), by setting them to connect to the remote host (assuming the service is available from the outside).

**Update:** if what you want is a text-based representation of your database, and you do not want to use a client like Workbench or phpmyadmin, please follow these steps:

- In Ubuntu, execute on a command line prompt:

  ```
   mysqldump -u root --all-databases > ~/database.sql
  ```
- Copy the `database.sql` file found on your home directory to your local pc using filezilla

If you want to export a single table and open it in an application like Excel, you can export it also in CSV format.

Comment: I check and found but this is not clean database.sql this is some .frm .ibd files, here some way for found clear database.sql file which i can easy download on my pc ?

Comment: @nikolr8 Yes, those .frm and .ibd files *are* your database. If you want a logical export of the contents ".sql", please use the tools commented on the last paragraph. In particular, have a look at mysqldump: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: i open this .frm and .ibd with notpead ++ but this is hard to read there some other solution for read this clear ?

Comment: Using notepad on a binary file will just produce gibberish - try [mysqlfrm](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqlfrm.html), [Percona's data recovery tool](http://www.percona.com/software/mysql-innodb-data-recovery-tools) and TwinDB's [tools](https://twindb.com/).